# BitmapImage download fail in Windows Phone 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I am trying to read read a `BitmapImage` from local storage. The path is selected by `FileOpenPicker`. But when I try to convert it into `Byte[]`, it fails. It seems like image is not downloaded at all, because `image.PixelWidth` returns '0'.

```
StorageFile storageFile = args.Files[0];
//var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
//var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
//await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
BitmapImage wb = new BitmapImage(new Uri(storageFile.Path));
byte[] pixeBuffer = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     WriteableBitmap wbit = new WriteableBitmap(wb.PixelWidth,wb.PixelHeight);
     Stream s1 = wb.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
     s1.CopyTo(ms);
     pixeBuffer = ms.ToArray();
}
```

The program crashes at

`WriteableBitmap wbit = new WriteableBitmap(wb.PixelWidth,wb.PixelHeight);`

I have checked that `storageFile.Path` points to right path, I have tried `URL` from internet too but same results.

I am new to C# and don't know how to trigger exception handling for windows phone, please guide me if it may help.

Answer (score 0):

After calling the decoder you should be doing something like:

```
try
{
    PixelDataProvider provider = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(decoder.BitmapPixelFormat, decoder.BitmapAlphaMode, new BitmapTransform(), ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
    byte[] pixelBuffer = provider.DetachPixelData();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

The try/catch block is the way you would want to catch exceptions in your code so I included it too.